# Why is NSLog out of order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

So I thought that I had the startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue on the main thread, but apparently that is not the case since I am getting NSLog updates for it after NSLogs that are supposed to come after.

```
2017-03-26 14:01:40.422661 Pneumonia Diagnosing App[950:200771] File 
accel.wav being overwritten...
...
2017-03-26 14:01:40.617392 Pneumonia Diagnosing App[950:200771] j=229320, finalfilelength = 229320, and i=114704, and filelength = 114660
2017-03-26 14:01:40.622864 Pneumonia Diagnosing App[950:200771] number: 66 Accelval: 0.004889
2017-03-26 14:01:40.623466 Pneumonia Diagnosing App[950:200771] number: 67 Accelval: 0.005058
```

I set up the startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue like this:

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error) {
        CMAcceleration userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;
        float accelval = userAcceleration.y*9.81;
        count = count + 1;
        NSString *accelvalue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f\n",accelval];
        //NSLog(@"number: %d Accelval: %f",count, accelval);
        NSFileHandle *myHandle;
        myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [myHandle writeData:[accelvalue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [myHandle closeFile];
    }];
```

Where I believe mainQueue is the main thread.

In my code I want the accelerometer values to be recorded to a csv and then after a lot of processing I want them put into a wav file.

After the startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue block (which occurs with hitting record button), the stop button is hit and this occurs:

```
[motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
        [recordbuttonimage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    recordbuttonstatus=0;
    playbuttonimage.enabled=TRUE;
    [playbuttonimage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [recorder stop];
        // Process CSV File on new Thread
        [self prepareaccelvalsforwav];
        // Combine data channels
        [self combinechannels];
```

The code that logs the line that is supposed to come after occurs in the combine channels method and I have shared some of it below.

After the creation of the wav, I have the log tell me the index of the byte in the wav and the audio length of the file:

```
FILE *finaldata = fopen([finalaudiofilepath UTF8String], "ab");
                                       i=44;
                                   k=4096;
                                   j=0;
                                       for (j = 0; j < (mixedaudiobufferlength);) {
                                           buffer3[0] = audiobytedatabuffer[k];
                                           buffer3[1] = audiobytedatabuffer[k + 1];
                                           buffer3[2] = accelbytedatabuffer[i];
                                           buffer3[3] = accelbytedatabuffer[i + 1];

                                           j = j + 4;
                                           i = i + 2;
                                           k = k + 2;
                                           fwrite(buffer3,1,4,finaldata);
                                           fflush(finaldata);
                                       }
                                   NSLog(@"j=%d, finalfilelength = %d, and i=%d, and filelength = %llu",j,mixedaudiobufferlength,i,accelfileSize);
                                       fclose(finaldata);
```

You can see that in the logs I posted.  However then the accelerometer NSLog pops up again.  What can I do to prevent this and have the accelerometer stop recording values before it hits the writing of the wav file?

Comment: You have left out half your code. [Edit] your question to include the code that logs `j=229320, finalfilelength = ...`. Be sure to include enough context to be clear.

Comment: What is the recorder object? Maybe it has a delegate method it will call to indicate that recording is done - if so, you could then start your post-processing in that method.